# Adding Class in Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I add here a class name?

```
 Html.ActionLink(
       item.Name, 
       "GetProducts", 
       "Products", 
        new { CityName = item.CityName.UnderScore(), CategoryName = item.Name.UnderScore() },
        null);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this [Html.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) overload method

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues,
    IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes
)
```

your example

```
Html.ActionLink(
   item.Name, 
   "GetProducts", 
   "Products", 
    new { CityName = item.CityName.UnderScore(), CategoryName = item.Name.UnderScore() },
    new { @class="some_class" });
```

Comment: Using the `@` symbol is how you use any C# keyword as something other than a keyword. Most times people will just try to name it something else but in cases like this where it HAS to be called `class` (due to it mapping to an HTML attribute), prefixing it with `@` is your only option.